# React - there is an another way to handle updated state rather than hardcoding all functions it in the callback part of the setState method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working in React and I have tried to handle new state in some function.

But that didn't work:

- my code then failed to update the value,
- there was some late in the update state rather than update immediately
- the function called in the callback part passed `null` as argument rather than `e`

So after some trials, I have hardcoded all my functions.

So I have hardcoded all my code in the callback area. Now it works fine. But I still wonder how to handle the new state in a more refined way rather than hardcode all function in the callback part.

Here my `handleChange` function:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("state in checkForm: ", this.state);

  if (e.target.name === "email") {
    let emailValue = e.target.value.trim()
    if (
      typeof(emailValue) === 'string' &&
      emailValue.length >= 1 &&
      validator.isEmail(emailValue)
    ) {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({},
            this.state[e.target.name], {
              validation: true
            }, {
              value: e.target.value
            })
        },
        () => {
          let validatePassword = this.state.password.validation;
          let validateEmail = this.state.email.validation;
          if (validateEmail && validatePassword) {
            this.setState({
              validateForm: true,
              nameSubmit: "onSubmit"
            });
            console.log("state email: ", this.state)
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: Object.assign({},
          this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: false
          })
      });
      this.setState({
        nameSubmit: "offSubmit",
        validateForm: false
      });
    }
  }

  if (e.target.name === "password") {
    let regexCheck = RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}");
    let password = e.target.value.trim()
    if (
      typeof(password) === 'string' &&
      password.length >= 1 &&
      regexCheck.test(password)
    ) {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: Object.assign({},
            this.state[e.target.name], {
              validation: true
            }, {
              value: e.target.value
            })
        },
        () => {
          let validatePassword = this.state.password.validation;
          let validateEmail = this.state.email.validation;
          if (validateEmail && validatePassword) {
            this.setState({
              validateForm: true,
              nameSubmit: "onSubmit"
            });
            console.log("state password : ", this.state)
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: Object.assign({},
          this.state[e.target.name], {
            validation: false
          })
      });
      this.setState({
        nameSubmit: "offSubmit",
        validateForm: false
      });
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see all the code is directly hardcoded in the `setState` callback part. I wonder how to create a more flexible way to make my callback,

Any hint would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so I don't know what you mean, but I understand that you wanna break your main function in some another small function, right? If that does not help you, put the complete code here to better analyze.

#### Code

```
  // Validations
  isValidEmail = (emailValue) => {
    return typeof emailValue === 'string' &&
           emailValue.length >= 1 &&
           validator.isEmail(emailValue);
  }

  isValidPassword = (password) => {
    const pattern = RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}");
    return typeof password === 'string' &&
           password.length >= 1 &&
           pattern.test(password);
  }

  // updates
  updateEmail = (name, email) => {
    if (isValidEmail(email)) {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: {
          ...this.state[e.target.name],
          validation: true,
          value: e.target.value
        }
      },
        () => {
          let validatePassword = this.state.password.validation;
          let validateEmail = this.state.email.validation;

          if(validateEmail && validatePassword) {
            this.setState({validateForm: true,
                          nameSubmit:"onSubmit"});
            console.log("state email: ", this.state)
          }
        }
      );

      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: {
        ...this.state[name],
        validation: false,
      },
      nameSubmit:"offSubmit",
      validateForm: false
    });
  }

  updatePassword = (name, password) => {
    if (this.isValidPassword(password)) {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: {
          ...this.state[name],
          validaition: true,
          value,
        }
      },
      () => {
        let validatePassword = this.state.password.validation;
        let validateEmail = this.state.email.validation;
        if(validateEmail && validatePassword) {
          this.setState({validateForm: true, nameSubmit:"onSubmit"});
          console.log("state password : ", this.state);
        }
      });

      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: {
        ...this.state[name],
        validaition: false,
      },
      nameSubmit:"offSubmit",
      validateForm: false
    });
  }

  // main fuction
  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "email" ) this.updateEmail(name, value.trim())
    if (name === "password") this.updatePassword(name, value.trim())
  }
```

So, first of all, I refactor the validation hardcode to a function which called `isValidEmail` and `isValidPassword`.

After that, I extracted in the `handleChange` content of each `if` to a new method called `updatedEmail` and `updatePassword` passing your current name and value.

I use `return` inside `if` to avoid `else` (It's a best practice I recommend).
Another thing, I use `spread` instead of `Object.assign`, much better to see (I recommend too)

And finally I just called the methods passing what it needs (name and value);

I hope it help you ;)